# Wireless mouse not connecting

Tags: 18.04, wireless, bluetooth, mouse, hardware

I am using a wireless mouse. When I try to connect the mouse to the PC, it shows that it is connected But it doesn't work. Same for my T6 headphone.
Thes devices perfectly fine on my Macbook and Windows 10 PC. I am not good in programming, so if anyone can tell me what to do it would help a lot.
My Linux version is 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Since you tagged Bluetooth am I to assume by wireless you mean Bluetooth?

Comment: Yes.it was a wireless bluetooth muse.